# Performance issue in JavaFx with setText on a label

Tags: java, swing, javafx

i want to write a Java Fx application under os linux gentoo (32bit) that measure the volume through a pipe and show the value on a label with .setText() method.
The update rate on the label is every 20 milli seconds. Means method label.setText(string) is called every 20 ms.
In this case the CPU performance of the JVM is very high. About 30% !!!
If i do the same with java swing technologie the cpu performance is about 7% !!
The traget hardware is a E3825 DualCore Intel Atom with 2 GB Ram (embedded system)
Oracel java version is jre 1.8.0.102
The problem still exist with other linux distributions and also on windows 10 IoT.

Very strange is that the performance using swing is much better.
I tried to set the text on a canvans in fx. It is better but not much.

Has ever observed the same behavior ?

Thx for anwers.

Attached an example with an counter on a label every 10 ms. Do i something wrong ?

Here a code example for java Fx:

```
      package appl;

  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.application.Platform;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.control.Button;
  import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
  import javafx.scene.text.Font;
  import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
  import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

  public class Main_javafx extends Application {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                           launch(args);
            }

            @Override
            public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
                           Label label = new Label("0000000000");
                           Button button = new Button("start");
                           VBox root = new VBox();
                           root.getChildren().add(label);
                           root.getChildren().add(button);
                           label.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.NORMAL, FontPosture.REGULAR, 100));
                           primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                           primaryStage.show();
                           button.setOnAction(e -> {
                           new Thread(() -> {
                           for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                               try {
                                               Thread.sleep(10);
                               }
                               catch (Exception ex) {
                               }
                               int ii = i;
                               Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                               label.setText(String.valueOf(ii));
                               });
                           }
                           }).start();

                           });
                           primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> Platform.exit());
            }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test in Swing, but I did get about a 100% improvement in CPU usage when using this code instead of yours:

```
public class Main_javafx extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label();
        Button button = new Button("start");
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        label.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.NORMAL, FontPosture.REGULAR, 100));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        IntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        label.textProperty().bind(count.asString());
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), e -> count.set(count.get() + 1)));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        button.setOnAction(e -> timeline.play());

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I didn't check why this code uses less CPU, but my guess either the binding is faster than manually updating and/or the thread wakeup-sleep cycle is slower than that of the `Timeline`.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the feedback. I tested your code on my Atom target PC but the performance is more or less the same. Little better with your code. It looks like the atom processor has some problems with the javafx technology.

On my desktop PC (Intel i5) there is no performance difference.
Hmm, very strange

Comment: @Todde I'm also running on i5. Your code used about 2% CPU, mine used about 1%. I assumed that on slower CPUs the difference would amplify. I suggest you submit a bug report to Oracle or OpenJFX with the code comparison and explanation.